# How can I avoid the user to click another edit button to another row?

Tags: vue.js

I want to avoid the user to click another button (edit button) in another row when the update is not done yet. I want the user to click the save button first before editing another row. How can I remove the textbox or back it to original form when clicking the save button? This is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2mh5yjeb/4/

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    editMode: false,
    users: [
      { name: 'mimi', email: 'wewe@s.com'},
      { name: 'sam', email: 'some@mk.com'},
      { name: 'kev', email: 'wewe'}
    ],
    editedUser: null
  },
  methods: {
    saveData () {

    },
    editData (user) {
      this.beforEditCache = user
      this.editedUser = user
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can define a data named **editDisabled** and bind it to editButton as **:disabled="editDisabled"**.

```html
 <button @click="editData(user)":disabled='editDisabled'>edit</button>
```

2. In your methods **saveData()** and **editData()** make below operations accordingly to disable the edit buttons when click to an edit and enable it again after save button is clicked

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    editMode: false,
    users: [
      { name: 'mimi', email: 'wewe@s.com'},
      { name: 'sam', email: 'some@mk.com'},
      { name: 'kev', email: 'wewe'}
    ],
    editedUser: null,
    editDisabled: false
  },
  methods: {
    saveData () {
      this.editDisabled = false
      this.editUser = null
      this.beforEditCache = null
      this.editedUser = null
    },
    editData (user) {
      this.editDisabled = true
      this.beforEditCache = user
      this.editedUser = user
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3jL1uah/3/), hope it helps :)